# Bootstrap- Left Columns Make the right columns move downwards when expanded

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns inside a container. The left column is actually a filter and I want it to expand and collapse without moving the right column of the NEXT ROW downwards.
[image]

In the image you can see the **"Speciality"** Box. When I click on the arrow at the bottom of that box. the menu inside expands. It makes the column under it **Charges** to move downwards, which is okay.

But Along with the charges box. the column next to it also goes down. I want Right Columns to stay where they are. And only the left ones to move up and down.
Any leads ?

Here's my HTML code

```
<div class="container">
           <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="content_left">
                <span class="expand-collapse-text exp"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>  </span>
                     <div class="left-title"> Speciality </div>
                         <div class="content-left1">
                             <span class="expand-collapse-text exp" > <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></span>
                         <div class="left-title"> Multi Speciality </div>
                            <div class="left_options">
                               <input value="1" id="ca1" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca"><label for="ca1"><span></span>Heart</label>                 <br>

                               <input value="2" id="ca2" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca"><label for="ca2"><span></span>General</label>                   <br>

                               <input value="3" id="ca3" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca"><label for="ca3"><span></span>Dental</label>                    <br>

                               <input value="16" id="ca16" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca"><label for="ca16"><span></span>Maternity</label>                  <br>

                               <input value="17" id="ca17" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca"><label for="ca17"><span></span>Orthopedic</label>                 <br>

                               <input value="18" id="ca18" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca"><label for="ca18"><span></span>Pediatric</label>                  <br>

                               <input value="19" id="ca19" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca"><label for="ca19"><span></span>Mental Health</label>

                                     <br>
                           </div>
                               <span class="expand-collapse-text exp"> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i> </span>
                                 <div class="left-title"> Speciality </div>
                               <span class="expand-collapse-text exp"> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i> </span>
                                 <div class="left-title"> Speciality </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
        </div>




<div class="col-xs-9 right-box">


    <div class="content_header col-md-12">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img src="#" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 Hospital_name">
            Cloud Nine Hospital
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 Hospital_speciality Hospital_type">
            Maternity Hospital
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 hospital_location Hospital_location">
            Bangalore
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1">
            ★★★★★
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            4.2

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Hospital_Details">
        <div class="col-xs-5" style="margin-left: -3.55%;">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 fee">
            Consultation fee: <span style="margin-left: 10%; color: skyblue">Rs: 500</span> <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: gainsboro">Onwards</span>
            <br>
            <br>

            Ward Charges <span style="margin-left: 13.5%; color: skyblue">Rs: 500</span> <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: gainsboro">Onwards</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            Contact: <span style="margin-left: 23%; color: darkblue">Jayanagar</span> <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: skyblue">9785461238</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                    <li><img src="#"/></li>
                    <li><img src="#"/></li>
                    <li><img src="#"/></li>
                    <li><img src="#"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-5"> View More Details <span> > </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-5">
                    <input type="submit" value="Book Appointment" class="appointment" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
        </div>     




        <!-- Column two-->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="div col-xs-3">
            <div class="content_left">
              <span class="expand-collapse-text exp"> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>  </span>
                <div class="left-title">
                    Charges <select name="Charges">
                                   <option>In Rupees </option>
                                   <option></option>
                            </select> 
                </div>
                                 <div class="content-left1"> 
                                  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly >
                                   <div id="slider-range"></div> 
                                   <br>
                                   <input type="text" id="amount1" readonly>
                                   <div id="slider-range1"></div> 
                               </div>
            </div>
        </div>

   <div class="col-xs-9 right-box">
     <div class="content_header col-md-12">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img src="#" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 Hospital_name">
            Cloud Nine Hospital
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 Hospital_speciality Hospital_type">
            Maternity Hospital
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 hospital_location Hospital_location">
            Bangalore
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1">
            ★★★★★
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            4.2

        </div>
    </div>

      <div class="Hospital_Details">
        <div class="col-xs-5" style="margin-left: -3.55%;">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 fee">
            Consultation fee: <span style="margin-left: 10%; color: skyblue">Rs: 500</span> <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: gainsboro">Onwards</span>
            <br>
            <br>

            Ward Charges <span style="margin-left: 13.5%; color: skyblue">Rs: 500</span> <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: gainsboro">Onwards</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            Contact: <span style="margin-left: 23%; color: darkblue">Jayanagar</span> <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: skyblue">9785461238</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                    <li><img src="#"/></li>
                    <li><img src="#"/></li>
                    <li><img src="#"/></li>
                    <li><img src="#"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-5"> View More Details <span> > </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-5">
                    <input type="submit" value="Book Appointment" class="appointment" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: From what I see, you need to include the `.row` class in your HTML. That way you can control the grid better. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

Comment: Can you put this into bootply or jsfiddle ?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/9rC5Bcmnbw did a bootply for you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure your markup. Looking at your page design I think at higher level it should have only 1 container and it should contain 2 columns. So your "Specialty" and "Charges" section should come under 1 column i.e "col-xs-3" and other will have "col-xs-9 right-box".

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/9rC5Bcmnbw#)

Comment: Thank you soo much.. that's exactly what I wanted. :)